# Check if empty and convert row from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i try to convert from a row in sheet1 to sheet2 ,
if that cell was empty input nothing " "
but if that cell have string input "*"

i try this but it not working
i want to check cell by cell from one row in sheet1 to one row in sheet2

```
sub convert()

dim iCell as Range
dim aCell as Range

For each iCell in Range("C35:AF35").Cells
  For each aCell in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E40:AH40").Cells

  if isempty(aCell) then
       iCell.Value = " "
  else 
       iCell.Value = "*"
  end if

next aCell

next iCell

End SUB
```

Answer (score 1):

`IsEmpty(Range)` doesn't always return true when there is no value in the cell.  It is recommended to use: `Len(Range) = 0`

The main problem with the code is that it is iterating over `aCell` for each `iCell`.  Only the last `aCell` value is being used to set the `iCell`.

Here is how to iterate over the ranges using the cell indices:

```
Sub Convert()
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Target As Range

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E40:AH40")
    Set Target = Range("C35:AF35")
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To Source.Count
        If Len(Source(n)) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = " "
        Else
            Target.Value = "*"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Retrieve Flags for Blanks and Non-Blanks

[image]

```vb
Sub RetrieveRangeFlags()

    ' Define constants.

    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "C35:AF35"
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "E40"
    Const YES_FLAG As String = "*" ' has a value; is not blank
    Const NO_FLAG As String = "" ' usually not a space " "; is blank

    ' Reference the workbook.

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source range.

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_RANGE)
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to an array
    ' (simplified, assuming there are at least two cells).
    
    Dim Data(): Data = srg.Value
    
    ' Write the array's upper limits (rows and columns) to variables.
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count ' or ' ... = UBound(Data, 1)'
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count ' or ' ... = UBound(Data, 2)'
    
    ' Loop through the elements (rows and columns) of the array and replace
    ' each value with the appropriate flag.
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, sStr As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            sStr = CStr(Data(r, c))
            If Len(sStr) = 0 Then ' is blank
            ' Or:
            'If IsEmpty(sStr) Then ' is empty
                Data(r, c) = NO_FLAG
            Else ' is not blank (empty)
                Data(r, c) = YES_FLAG
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    ' Reference the destination range which is of the same size
    ' as the source range.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(rCount, cCount)
    
    ' Write the results (flags) from the array to the destination range.
    
    drg.Value = Data
    
    ' Inform.

    MsgBox "Flags retrieved.", vbInformation
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
For each iCell in Range("C35:AF35").Cells
```

without qualifying it refers to the activesheet. Qualify it like this (as you did in your code's next statement)

```
For each iCell in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C35:AF35").Cells
```

where Sheet2 is the target worksheet name.
From the information what you gave, i can only found this as a cause of the code's problem.